# what a blank "cout" does?

Tags: c++, c++11

What does it differ a blank cout using or not? 
This code gives correct answer for using cout<<"";

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        long long input, ans=1, vagsesh;
        double vag;
        cin>>input;

        while(input>0 || vag>0)
        {
            vag = ((log10(input))/(log10(2)));

            cout<<""; // if this is not used, it leads to a wrong answer

            vagsesh = vag;
            input -= pow(2,vagsesh);
            if(input > 0)
                {
                    ans++;
                }
            if(input==0)
                {
                    break;
                }
        }

        cout<<ans<<endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

What is done by cout<<""; here?

Comment: It may prevent optimization; An old-fashioned trick. (Compiler options/flags?)

Comment: If `input <= 0`, the first loop condition check will read from `vag` which has not been initialized yet. This causes Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: "leads to wrong answer" is pretty vague for an error message. What do you expect and what happens instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cout << ""` is not what I would consider a "blank cout". A "blank cout" would be the following:

```
std::cout;
```

In fact, `std::cout << ""` would take manipulators into account. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::setw(10);
    std::cout << "";
}
```

Output: 10 spaces.

Another observable effect of `std::cout << ""`, even without any manipulators, would be when you redirect the output of your program into a file (with something like `myprogram.exe > file.txt` or `./myprogram > file.txt`). `std::cout` then writes into the file and you could observe a change in the file's modification date even if the contents would remain the same.

---

As for your code, you have undefined behaviour in it:

> ```
>     double vag;
>     cin>>input;
>
>     while(input>0 || vag>0)
> ```

`vag` is not initialised when you try to read from it. Perhaps this causes the strange behaviour? Because, of course, in an otherwise correct program, `cout << ""` cannot possibly change the result. Try this to prevent undefined behaviour:

```
double vag = 0.0;
```

---

P.S.: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is not standard C++. You should change it to `#include <iostream>`, or, generally, to specific header includes. And `using namespace std;` is a bad habit; even if it doesn't hurt in your example program, beginners sometimes use it at global scope in header files, where it can wreak havoc in the long run.